# Exchange 2010 Message Tracking

Tags: exchange-2010, log-files

I was wondering  if when i use the get-messagetrackinglog command i would also see rejected emails. Like if external user A sends an email to internal user B and got rejected for spam, could i see the email with the command?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's multiple log entries for each message as it moves through the server, so yes, you'd see messages that were rejected before getting to the user's mailbox.  Those messages would have their subject and sender address recorded, but not the body or other headers.

Comment: Awesome!Exactly the answer is was looking for Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to see that in the RecipientStatus section of the output of that command.